# Excel: show matches occurrences

Tags: excel

I have 1 column with dates and another with user log ins. I want to see how many times a user logged in per day.

```
 02 January 2013    wright
 02 January 2013    wright
 02 January 2013    paula
 02 January 2013    john
 02 January 2013    paula
 03 January 2013    john
 03 January 2013    wright
```

I want to turn this into

```
              02 January 2013   03 January 2013
 wright              2                1
 paula               2                0
 john                1                1
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thank you for any help.

I understand that I can use pivot table to change the spreadsheet into this:

```
         02 January 2013   03 January 2013
wright
paula
john
```

But do not understand how I can use pivot table to add the instances of each logged entry to a date.

Comment: Use **Pivot table**, quite simple Excel feature...

Comment: if you mean columns in your second line then you can use a pivot table for what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Pivot table, perhaps?

Comment: I'm thinking ... pivot table :).

Comment: Has anyone mentioned Pivot Tables yet?

Comment: I can pivot table, yes, but how can I provide the 'Value' data without creating seperate addition of each data?

Comment: If you call the first column `Date`, the second column `Names`, you can set your Pivot up like this: 1) Insert your Pivot Table 2) use `Name` as your Rows 3) use `Date` as your columns 4) drag `Date` into the values box. This will give you a count value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use VBA which gives you full control on the output.

Are you familiar with VBA? If so I can provide you the code.

Comment: What full control would `VBA` give you in this instance?

Comment: Validation control for example, to edit data based on a specific logic.

Comment: Also is there a way to move my explanaion to comments section of the main quesion? I dont see a add comment link for the main question.

Comment: I only see Share|Edit|Flag

Answer (score -1):

lets assume your list of dates in in column B and your list of user ids in in column C.

1. Generate a list of unique names

in this case I am arbitrarily generating the table in E9 as the top left corner. In E10 I place the following CSE formula (mean you press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).  You will know you have done it right when excel adds {} around the formula.  You cannot manually added them.

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX($C$2:$C$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$9:E9, $C$2:$C$20), 0))), "", INDEX($C$2:$C$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$9:E9, $C$2:$C$20), 0)))
```

1. Copy down as far as you need
2. Place a date in excel format in F9
3. Copy right as far as you need.  It should increase by one day for each column copied
4. In cell F10 place the following formula and copy and paste down and to the right as far as required.

   =COUNTIFS($C:$C,$E10,$B:$B,F$9)

[image: POC]

Having said all this a pivot table can do it much quicker and faster.